# PROJ.4 in QGIS Helmert

Tags: coordinate-system, proj

I am trying to create with PROJ a custom CRS in QGIS 3.2.0 - but I fail.

I have a local, cartesian coordinate system and a transformation report (2D-Helmert) with the following parameters: translation of the x-axis, translation of the y-axis, scale factor in ppm and rotation angles. With this Helmert-transformation the local coordinates should be transformed into cartesian WGS84 coordinates.

So I am trying something like this: 
proj=helmert
    x= 2956.5331  y= 5917.9548  z= -28.7120
    rx= -0° 00' 09.19941" ry= -0° 00' 02.81345" rz= -1° 39' 10.90398"  s= 1 + 0.1347 ppm

I get an error message - am I doing something completely wrong?

Glad about any answers...

Best
Susanne

Comment: That's not a 2D Helmert, but a 3D Helmert. It's normally used in XYZ space. Try using +TOWGS84=2956.5331,5917.9548,-28.7120,-9.19941,-2.81345,-5950.90398,0.1347 but the input data must be in lat/lon or maybe XYZ (3D Cartesian) not local projected coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, some things are wrong, see https://proj4.org/operations/transformations/helmert.html

- parameters should start with a +
- `+convention` is required (PROJ 5.2 onwards)
- rotations must be in arc seconds
- `proj.exe` expects latlon input, so you have to use `cct`
- you have to use 3D coordinates x y z for input

So you can try:

```
 cct -o cctout.txt +proj=helmert +convention=coordinate_frame +x=2956.5331 +y=5917.9548 +z=-28.7120 +rx= 9.19941 +ry=-2.81345 +rz=-5950.90398 +s=1000000.1347 HelmertIn.txt
```

Sad news at last: This works only in PROJ 5.2, not (yet) within GDAL and QGIS.